# How to delete production and activate beta testing apk

Tags: android, google-play, apk, beta

I had beta version of apk on google play, with version code = 1  (no alfa, no production).

I created a new version of Beta build and made a mistake of uploading it as a production build (live) (version code = 2). I couldn't find a way to remove it right away, so I uploaded new Beta right after that because testers needed it (version code = 3).

I need to remove the production version (version code=2) of the application of the store but to keep my Beta version available for testers (version code = 3).
How can I do that, or something that will have similar effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload an APK that only has a `TextView` "Coming soon" inside, with version code 4 and upload the same beta build with the version code 5.
Should pretty much have the same effect. There is no other way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.


What are my options here:


1. do what you said.

2. what would happend if I would unpublish app? will Beta be still available?

3. would it be wise to delete the app and create new one with the same name but different package?

Comment: @Slavisa If you unpublish your app, the beta also gets lost. You have no other choice than making this, if you want to keep the beta. Using a different package name is also not recommended. You might just do this, and then publish things if everything is okay.

Comment: can you explain why is not recommended to delete the current app and create new with different package (beside that testers will not get the update but will needed to be navigated to new link for downloading beta)? thank you for your help and time

Comment: @Slavisa Because that's more work for you, if you change the package name ;)

Comment: but it would solve my problem, wouldn't it? Current app would be deleted from Google Play?

Comment: @Slavisa If you really want to go through the struggle of changing the package name, go on. But make a backup of the current project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88847/discussion-between-slavisa-and-max).